# get text from response of shell command

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I want to write a script to automate a repetitive task I do.

I issue this command:

```
heroku pgbackups:capture --expire
```

And I get this response

> MY_DB_URL (DATABASE_URL)  ----backup--->  b677

I then issue this command with the capture number (b677 in the above)

```
curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url b677`
```

How can I parse the text and place the value into the next command?

Comment: You mean automate this process without having to remember and type the capture number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only a matter of parsing the output of the first command and saving it into a variable:

```
capnum=$(heroku pgbackups:capture --expire | grep -- "--->" | awk '{print $NF}')
```

And then execute,

```
curl -o latest.dump $(heroku pgbackups:url ${capnum})
```

Alternatively, you may say:

```
curl -o latest.dump $(heroku pgbackups:url $(heroku pgbackups:capture --expire | grep -- "--->" | awk '{print $NF}'))
```

Answer (score 1):

More ways:

```
read __ __ __ URL < <(exec heroku pgbackups:capture --expire)
curl -o latest.dump "$URL"

curl -o latest.dump $(exec heroku pgbackups:capture --expire | cut -f 4 -d ' ')

curl -o latest.dump $(exec heroku pgbackups:capture --expire | sed 's|.* ||')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the format of the capture number is *always* the same, you can use

```
captureNumber=`heroku pgbackups:capture --expire | grep -o [a-Z][0-9]*$`

curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url ${captureNumber}`
```

or, perhaps more general, detect the last space and use the remainder of the line:

```
captureNumber=`heroku pgbackups:capture --expire | grep -o \s.*$`
```

Adjust the regex if there are different formats I don't know about, or go with devnull's answer if the format is not well-captured by regex.

Answer (score 0):

Its doable using sed and a shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
s=`heroku pgbackups:capture --expire`
id=`echo ${s} | sed -e "s/^.*> \(b[0-9]*\)$/\1/"`
url=`echo heroku pgbackups:url ${id}`
curl -o last.dump "${url}"
```

This is not the most beautiful shell script, but it can work as prove of concept.